# Difficulty understanding code which retrieves a filename from a file control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in a project. I understand that it outputs the file from a file input control. The issue is that I don't understand the working of `var filename = e.target.files[0].name`. Please help me out, if you can.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    $('#choose').html(fileName);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the line `e.target.files[0].name` down in to sections:

- `e` is the Event object passed to the jQuery event handler function as an argument.
- `target` is the property which contains a reference to the element which raised the event
- `files` is a collection of the files selected within the `input type="file"` control. If the control has the `multiple` attribute set on it, it's possible for there to be more than 1 file selected, in which case you would need a loop.
- `[0]` retrieves only the first selected file from the `files` collection - in the same manner as you access an array by index.
- `name` gets the filename of that file.